# Returning a single primary key from a group of repeated values

Tags: sql

I want to fill a new table (Items) from another one already filled (History) and kind of a messed up.

History columns:
PK1 PK2 SERIAL ID_NUMBER DATE ...

Items table should have SERIAL as PK and a unique ID_NUMBER (Like a PK too)

So I want to select from History, several columns, with the condition that SERIAL and ID_NUMBER would be unique.

I have achieve to return just SERIAL and ID_NUMBER w/o repetition with group by clause, but when I ask for other columns it says that they have to be within the group by clause as well. I put them in and return me more records I don't want.

So what I want is to retrieve JUST ONE entire row from the repeated values. And of course the unique ones

Let's say:
`+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| PK1  PK2  ID_NUMBER  SERIAL    DATE      MORE_COLUMNS...     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 123   1     ABC21     ZXC1   20-1-2011                       |
| 123   2     ABC00     ZXC2   30-1-2011                       |
| 234   1     ABC00     ZXC2   20-4-2011                       |
| 345   1     ABC21     ZXC1   10-5-2011                       |
| 567   1     ASD31     QWE1   23-1-2012                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+`

I want to return:

`+--------------------------------------------------------+
| PK1 PK2 ID_NUMBER  SERIAL    DATE      MORE_COLUMNS... |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 123  1   ABC21      ZXC1    20-1-2011                  |
| 234  1   ABC00      ZXC2    30-1-2011                  |
| 567  1   ASD31      QWE1    23-1-2012                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------+`

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try to merge `PK1` and `PK2` for example in `oracle` you can use `PK1||PK2` or `CONCAT(PK1,PK2)` in `mysql`,this query works fine in `oracle`:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE (PK1||PK2) IN (SELECT MIN(PK1||PK2) from YOUR_TABLE
 GROUP BY ID_NUMBER,SERIAL);
```

Comment: Worked with (...) WHERE (PK1||PK2) IN (... GOURP BY ID_NUMBER) AND (PK1||PK2) IN (... GROUP BY SERIAL).
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct ID_NUMBER,  SERIAL,    DATE,  MORE_COLUMNS 
from (the first query) src
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get back one of the PK1, PK2 values, you can do

```
SELECT
     MIN(PK1) as [PK1]
    ,MIN(PK2) as [PK2]
    ,ID_NUMBER
    ,SERIAL
    ,DATE
    , . . . 
FROM ( . . .)
GROUP BY ID_NUMBER, SERIAL, DATE, ...
```